# DataGridView_RowHeaderMouseClick Event Shows error Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, datagridview, webforms, windows

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I have use uniqueidentifier as my id in sql server database error is showing in the first line where `ID = ...`

```
private void DataGridViewDischarge_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   ID = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridViewDischarge.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
   TxtHeadOverNotch.Text = DataGridViewDischarge.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   TxtDischargeQ.Text = DataGridViewDischarge.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `DataGridViewDischarge.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: the value is not convertible to integer put break point and check what value is coming

Comment: **uniqueidentfier** is guid i think not **integer**

Comment: e.rowindex is showing 0 means ID is coming 0

Comment: ya but how to covert it to Guid??

Comment: @JaydeepChavda That's the `RowIndex` for that particular row, it doesn't contain the `ID` value. You need to inspect: `DataGridViewDischarge.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unique Identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) is **GUID** in sql server and **`GUID`** cannot be represent as **`int`** so you have to parse it to GUID, see [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity):

```
Guid id  = Guid.Parse(DataGridViewDischarge.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgv_expenditure_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dgv = dgv_expenditure.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Cells[0].Value);
    tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;

    loadform(id);
}

private void loadform(int id)
{
    //   throw new NotImplementedException();
    SanmolCAEntities1 _db = new SanmolCAEntities1();

    var u = _db.a_expenditure.Where(p => p.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    txt_name.Text = u.name;
    txt_CreateBy.Text = u.createby;
    dateTimePicker_excrdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    txt_updateBy.Text = u.updateby;
    dateTimePicker_exupdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
}
```

error in this line:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Cells[0].Value);
```

this is error;
input string was not in a correct format